# Using XAML <Binding> sytax to bind a DataContext?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF UserControl which allows the editing of an data object (VariableDataGroup). When I use the following syntax the binding works and my user control displays correctly:

```
<vdi:VariableDataPageView DataContext="{Binding VariableData}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" >
```

Where *VariableData* is a property on the parent screen's ViewModel.
However, when I try and use the "<Binding>" syntax then my user control doesn't display the data.

```
<vdi:VariableDataPageView  Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" >
    <Binding  Path="VariableData" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
        <!--<Binding.ValidationRules>
            <validation:VDIComittedValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" />
        </Binding.ValidationRules>-->
    </Binding>
</vdi:VariableDataPageView>
```

The reason I want to switch to using the  syntax is to use a custom validation rule to fit in with the exiting code.

**First Question:** What would be the equivalent  syntax to 'DataContext="{Binding VariableData}"' ?

**Second Question:** Is there a recommended way of performing validation in a UserControl and integrating that with the validation on the parent view? The way I think it should work is that the UserControl performs all its own validation and just passes a validated yes/no result to the parent page but the whole WPF model of programming is new to me.

Thanks,
Canice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalent syntax to `DataContext="{Binding VariableData}"`

```
<vdi:VariableDataPageView  Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" >
    <vdi:VariableDataPageView.DataContext>
        <Binding  Path="VariableData" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <!--<Binding.ValidationRules>
                <validation:VDIComittedValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>-->
        </Binding>
    </vdi:VariableDataPageView.DataContext>
</vdi:VariableDataPageView>
```

Comment: @OmegaMan Thanks, I'll give it a try tomorrow at work.

Comment: @canice This is not my post, I only edited it while reviewing. :-)